# Need Column data to be the ROW header for my query

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, crosstab

I am trying to use a LATERAL JOIN on a particular data set however i cannot seem to get the syntax correct for the query.

What am i trying to achieve:

Take the first column in the dataset (See picture) and use that as the Table headers (rows) and populate the rows with the data from the StringValue column

Currently it appears like this:

```
cfname              | stringvalue      |
----------------------------------------
customerrequesttype | newformsubmission|
Assignmentgroup     | ITDEPT           |
```

and I would like to have it appear as this:

```
customerrequesttype| Assignmentgroup|
-------------------------------------
newformsubmission  | ITDEPT
```

As mentioned i am very new to SQL i know limited basics

[image: screenshot of dataset]

Comment: Welcome to SO. You mean that the first row of your result set will always be the header?

Comment: i would like to take the first Column CFNAME and the results from that turned into ROWS and then assign the results from StringValue as a result for the new row created. apologies as im still very new to postgresSQL and SQL in general :)

Comment: maybe cross could help. Info here:https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tablefunc.html

Comment: @ecp my work place is hesitant to add anything additional to the default instance so makes it hard to install additional functions.